# Stripe recurring payments for 3DS source

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to use Stripe to charge cards recurrently every 30 days with amounts that oscilate.

From the docs I got that if there is a possibility that the card requires 3DS we should use Sources so I switched to sources ;)

From the source object stripe.js retrieves I look at `three_d_secure` param to decide whether to create a source object that requires 3DS or a normal card charging.

### The flow:

With JS I get the source object that has `three_d_secure` set to either *optional* or *required*. 
When it's set to *optional* after I retrieve the source with: `source = Stripe::Source.retrieve(source_id)` it looks like this:

```
"status": "chargeable",
"type": "card",
"usage": "reusable",
"card":{"exp_month":12,"exp_year":2032,"brand":"Visa",...
```

I attach it to a customer and charge it. I guess `usage: reusable` means that I can charge the card again later...

When `three_d_secure=='required'` I create a new `source` calling this:

```
source = Stripe::Source.create({
    amount: amount,
    currency: currency,
    type: 'three_d_secure',
    three_d_secure: {
      card: source_id, #src_xcvxcvxcvc
    },
    redirect: {
      return_url: return_url
    },
})
```

I redirect the user to the URL Stripe provides, user enters his 3DS PIN and gets back to my `return_url`. When Stripe redirects the user back to my return_url I retrieve the source again and get something like this:

`"status": "chargeable",
  "type": "three_d_secure",
  "usage": "single_use",
  "three_d_secure": {"card":"src_1B1JzQHopXUl9h9Iwk05JV1z","authenticated":true,"customer":null}`

I would expect that after passing the 3DS the source becomes reusable and chargeable until the date of expiry or so :|

My questions are:

1 Why is the 3DS source single_use? Is this like this only in sanbox environment or with the card I am using to test?

2 Can a 3DS protected card be charged again at all?

3 What's the correct approach to attach to customer sources (3DS or normal) that can be charged again and again?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because it is a `source payment token`, not a `source card token`. It expires on a due date or when is consumed. You can use `reusable` token to create `single_use` tokens. `reusable` one represents a `card source token`
2. Yes if a 3ds is `optional` or `not_supported`, no if `required`. If `required` then every payement needs to fulfill a 3ds.
3. Steps:

   - Create an `src_card_token` for a card or use saved one (`reusable`)
   - Create an `customer object` with an src from `src_card_token`
   - Create an `src_payment_token` for a customer using one of his saved cards (as token)
   - fullfil a 3ds redirect process if required.
   - create a charge

Comment: Thank you @sebastian. I'll try your steps when I arrive home! Cheers

Comment: In Spain the majority of banks requiere a 3DS flow for their cards if the amount exceedes x €. Does that mean that for those users I won't have an option of creating a new charge every month at all and that they'll have to manually do it by coming back to their profile? Thanks

Comment: @luigi7up this is not a correct way to do this. You need to use subscriptions not a standard payment. https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions and https://stripe.com/docs/sources/three-d-secure/subscriptions

Comment: I looked into subscriptions and they seem they might work, but I prefer an option of being able to manually charge a source when I need to :\ I got it working by charging the three_d_secure source and attaching the card source that comes with it to the customer for later charges. It seems like everything is ok, but... :) In the dashboard under the sources for the customer I have the card listed as chargeable adn as the default method. When I try to make another charge I get "Your Card was rejected by the bank" :\

Comment: You cannot charge a card that way, this is againts the law and the PCI compliance rules. Your only way is to use subsriptions for recurring payments.

Comment: "You cannot charge a card that way" I don't get the point of a card being "reusable" ? Also, why is subscription a valid approach if you can still modify the quantity and charge what you want :\ Thank you again

Comment: Confused... This article gives an impression that saving a card and charging it later at anypoint is totally valid approach: https://stripe.com/docs/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later In the end UBER does it, Amazon does it...

Comment: @luigi7up you can save the card details for later use but YOU CANNOT create a charge by yourself from this card. Beucause of saved card you do not have to create a card_source_token that is reausable again, but still REUSABLE token is for creating single_use_tokens, this is what reusable means here. So count `reusable` as saved card. Charging a card is different thing that require for example 3ds. if 3ds is optional you still cannot  create a payment token by yourself, because you are not authorized to do that and you are breaking the compliance pci law